# Magento 2, Custom Customer Address Attribute update issue

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2 Cloud. I have created a Customer Address Attribute customer_shipping_date using Admin Menu.

This attribute is not visible on frontend.

In sales_order_save_after observer I try to set/update it's value programmitically but when I edit order address in admin, it shows blank.

How can I set the value after order has been created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this as well, because it is a custom attribute you need to load 2 models in your constructor:

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory
){
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function updateCustomerAttribute($customerId)
{
    $customAttribute = 'your_custom_attribute_goes_here';
    $customAttributeValue = 'your_custom_attribute_value_goes_here';

    $customermodel = $this->_customer;
    $customer = $customermodel->load(customerId);
    $customerData = $customermodel->getDataModel();
    $customerData->setId($customerId);
    $customerData->setCustomAttribute($customAttribute, $customAttributeValue);
    $customermodel->updateData($customerData);

    $customerResource = $this->_customerFactory->create();
    $customerResource->saveAttribute($customermodel, $customAttribute);
}
```

I have tested this personally and it worked after a lot of hours of research and testing.